# Opensearch cache LDAP accounts until being restarted?

Tags: ldap, opensearch

I am trying to integrate Opensearch with openldap, and currently I am able to login to Opensearch-Dashboard with a user (say john) in ldap. However, after I delete user "john" from ldap, I can still login with user "john" with previously assigned group as if the user is cached by Opensearch once it logs in. The user remains cached until I restart Opensearch. I can no longer login with user "john" as expected after Opensearch is restarted.

Does anyone experience the same thing? or most likely I miss-configured somethinig?

I use Helm chart from https://github.com/opensearch-project/helm-charts (main branch) to deploy Opensearch.
The Docker image used is opensearchproject/opensearch:2.0.0-rc1

Answer (score 0):

After a few testings, it turns out the LDAP data will be cached for around 10 min.